# Entity framework getting IDs for multiple insert in foreach

Tags: entity-framework

When we insert multiple rows at the same time with Entity framework it's good to add these objects one by one and then commit in the end, instead of adding and comitting each time.

So in that case, how do I get IDs for those insertions?

Example:

```
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Subscription subscription = new Subscription();

            subscription.Amount = item.ItemTotal;
            this.ClientRepositories.LiveData.AddToSubscriptions(subscription);
// LiveData is db context via webservice proxy
            // how to get IDS of these insertions if you do not commit each time?

            int id = subscription.Id;
someOtherOperation(id); //i need to insert ID for each row that was inserted

        }

        this.ClientRepositories.LiveData.SaveChanges();
```

If I use commit inside for each time it adds new object I can easily get the latest inserted ID, but its not good to commit each time for multiple rows I heard.

Comment: Even if you add a bunch at the same time, the ID field if your entities should be updated after saving to the database. And if you have proper navigational properties between your entities, you can insert into multiple tables, referring the entities rather than ids directly, in a single commit.

Comment: can you please give name of you two tables and their relation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you are using auto incremented id's.  I think your going to have to keep a list of your subscription objects outside of your loop.  During each loop iteration, add the current subscription to the list.  After your execute 'SaveChanges();' The subscription id's will be automatically added.

Would look like this:

```
            List<Subscription> subList = new List<Subscription>();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Subscription subscription = new Subscription();

                subscription.Amount = item.ItemTotal;
                this.ClientRepositories.LiveData.AddToSubscriptions(subscription);
                subList.add(subscription);

            }

            this.ClientRepositories.LiveData.SaveChanges();
            /* At this point, each Subscription in your 'subList' should have an id */
```

Comment: I was thinking about that, but isn't there any like better way implemented in entity to do it? I am actually inserting multiple records into 2 tables at the same time, that is why I need those ids.

Comment: Hmm not that I am aware of.